# Layering iframe and video

Tags: html, css

I have a video which I want to play on top of an iFrame and then remove it when it finishes but I can't make the video appear above the iframe. Is there some trick to it? I've tried CSS z-index but it doesn't help. I have a code like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Enormous Wedding III</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class = "container"><span>
<div id = "game"><iframe src='...'></div>
<div id = "video"><video autoplay> <source src="menu.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video></div>
</span></div>

<script>
    var video = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0];
    var game = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0];

    video.onended = function(e) {
      video.style.display = "none";
    };
</script>

</body></html>
```

And a CSS file:

```
    html, body, .container {
    height: 100%;
}
.container {
    display: -webkit-flexbox;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

#game {
    z-index: 1;
}

#video {
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Why doesn't it work and how can I make the video appear on top of the iframe?

Answer (score 0):

Use `position: absolute;` on the child elements and `position: relative;` on the parent.

```
.container {
    position: relative;
}
iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
video {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

`z-index` requires position to be set to relative, absolute or fixed. By doing using position absolute you can put the elements where you want within the next element up the tree that is position relative, in this case `.container`

The example jsfiddle [shows this in action](http://jsfiddle.net/o4yem4Lc/1/)

Comment: Unfortunately applying this in my source doesn't solve the problem and also adding "position:relative" destroys the centering that the container used to give them :(

Comment: I'll need more detail of the specific problem, could you set up a jsfiddle? Also, you may need to: wrap the `position: relative;` container in the container that is centred; find some other way of centring the container; or try `position absolute;` on the conatiner

Comment: or, link to your source and I'll take a look ... as a reduced solution to the `z-index` overlay problem positioning like above solves the problem, however, there could be things interfering from elsewhere in the client build

Comment: Thank you a lot, would be great if you could take a look. Here's the full source (video is referenced locally): https://jsfiddle.net/q1q3xzvz/

Comment: you could try adding colours and seeing where things are for starters; then try removing bits of css and seeing which bits make it behave